# I am not being able to solve this problem of Continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that $[x] \sin^2(\pi x)$ is continuous at every integer point and
$[x] \cos^2 (\pi x)$ is discontinuous at every integer point.

Comment: What does $[x]$ mean?

Comment: Please use MathJax, I actually don't know what this [x] in brackets is supposed to denote.

Comment: I'm guessing it should be the nearest integer to $x$.

Comment: It is common notation for the floor function, the greatest integer $\leq x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sin(\pi x) = 0$ whenever $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $|\cos(\pi x)| = 1 \not= 0$ whenever $x \in \mathbb{Z}.$